# Long-run volatility forecast of a GARCH(1,1)

Tags: garch

Can I assume that "the long run volatility forecast of a GARCH(1,1) is higher in periods of high volatility than in periods of low volatility?

Comment: Could you please clarify whether *long run volatility forecast* implies the $h$-step ahead forecast, $\sigma_{t+h}$ for large $h$ or are you talking about the unconditional variance (also called the long-run variance) $\mathbb{V}ar\left(r_t\right) = \frac{\omega}{1 - \alpha - \beta}$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that it is about the unconditional variance.

Comment: Theoretically speaking, I would not assume the above. However, I would try to empirically justify it: Often you fit a GARCH model using a rolling-window, which yield a new set of parameter estimates at each fit. From the estimates you can back-out the unconditional variance for each set of estimated parameters and see whether it increases in periods of high-volatility. Be aware that, if you find empirical evidence that your statement is true, then it's an empirical observation and not an assumption.